# Why won't int variable come before char array in terms of addressing no matter how I code it in C?

Tags: c, stack, overflow, buffer, frames

I'm reading **Hacking: The Art of Exploitation (2nd Edition)**, and I'm currently on the section about buffer overflows.

In the first example, the variables are declared/initialized in this order:

```
int auth_flag = 0;
char password_buffer[16];
```

The example goes on to explain that you can use gdb to examine `auth_flag` and `password_buffer`'s addresses, and you'll notice that `auth_flag`'s address is higher than `password_buffer`'s. Things to keep in mind: I'm running all of this in Ubuntu within Virtualbox on a Macbook Pro (Intel processor, 64-bit).

I compiled the first example's code like this: `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -o auth_overflow auth_overflow.c`

As expected, `auth_flag`'s address is higher than `password_buffer`'s.

To remedy the problem presented above, the author explains you should switch the ordering of the declarations:

```
char password_buffer[16];
int auth_flag = 0;
```

I compiled the code the same way: `gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -o auth_overflow2 auth_overflow2.c`

Unfortunately, I did not see `auth_flag`'s address being lower than `password_buffer`'s. In fact, it was still higher. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The compiler will tend to arrange variables in order of decreasing alignment requirements to minimize padding. That said, it's strange that the `int` is always higher and not always lower. Anyway, you can't depend on the order of declaration making any sort of difference so it is a strange point for the book to make. Kudos for performing the experiment and finding the BS.

Comment: Also, welcome to SO and +1 for the eloquent wording.

Comment: I wonder why Potatoswatter didn't post his comment as an answer...

Comment: @brennan :-) Reading a mind of one who goes by a pseudonym such as potatoswatter is possibly well beyond my ken. But if I were to venture a guess, he wrote this as a comment to explain his +1 for the question which was incidentally well worded.

Comment: @Potato, when two values are pushed on the stack, the first one has a higher address, since it's filled from the top isn't it ?

Comment: @Samuel: On any modern platform, the stack pointer is adjusted by an `add` or similar instruction and then the space created is used. Local variables aren't pushed one by one.

Comment: I started typing in the comment box and ended up mostly answering the question… it happens.

Comment: @Joe, maybe it's treating the char array as if it has an alignment of 16. See if changing the size to 15 or 17 switches the ordering.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is allowed to choose whatever order it wants, in order to provide more optimal code, or even just random because it's easier to implement.  One thing you might try is `-O0` flag which disables all optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are free to rearrange variables as they feel is best. I believe that the only restriction in the order of struct members. Those must be in memory in the same order as declared in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread quite interesting:

http://www.mail-archive.com/avr-gcc-list@nongnu.org/msg05043.html

Quote: *In theory it can be done*

```
-fdata-section
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a security feature to prevent just the type of hacking you are talking about - There is a degree of randomization to where everything is stored in memory, so you can't for example find the memory allocated for a certain program, and go to the 1502nd byte where the function to open the high security vault locks sits, cause it isn't always in the same place in memory.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization for details on how this works.

Funny coincidence that you would encounter this, and that Matt Joiner would stumble on the answer while trying to burn apple.

Comment: On second thought... did you say Ubuntu is the active OS? I could be completely wrong if that's the case.

Comment: Firstly, the OP did say that he's running the experiment in a Ubuntu VM.  Secondly, Ubuntu has ASLR enabled too.  And thirdly, ASLR randomises the stack base, but doesn't randomise the relative positions of two stack variables.